# SSRS Report Builder 2.0 - Use with SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I'm starting to look into SSRS Report Builder 2.0, and I see in the documentation that it supports connections to SQL 2005.

Does anyone know if the reports made against SQL 2005 can then be upload to the SSRS 2005 website and ran from the site?  Or, can they only be run from the SSRS 2008 website if they were generated in Report Builder 2.0?

Comment: +1 for wishing and hoping. Report Builder 2.0 is so much better than 1.0 that they should have renamed the bloody thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not run a 2008 report on the 2005 engine, you can however run a 2005 report on the 2008 engine, it converts the report on-demand.

Here is a link to a similar q/a: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=350119&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. 2008 reports can only be run on a SSRS 2008 report server.
Paul